# Python: joining 2 lists of the same size

Tags: python, list, sum

Let's say I have 2 following lists:

list1 = [1,1,1,1]
list2 = [3,3,3,3]

I want the result of join to be:

list3 [4,4,4,4]

What's would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extremely similar to Ignacio's answer, but for a tiny bit more brevity:

```
list3 = [sum(i) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
```

or

```
list3 = map(sum, zip(list1, list2))
```

I prefer the map version myself.

**Edit:** As JBernardo rightly points out, if using Python 2.x you should replace zip with its iterator counterpart in itertools.izip for efficiency, but zip uses iterators by default in Python 3.

Comment: of course zip is the right choice for Python3. For 2.x you should prefer izip from itertools.
BTW, your solution is cleaner than Ignacio's.

Answer (score 9):

```
list3 = [x + y for (x, y) in itertools.izip(list1, list2)]
```

or

```
list3 = map(operator.add, list1, list2)
```